# Reusage of XML classes in Greendao

Tags: android, xml, orm, greendao, simple-framework

I use classes that were built for XML parsing (via SimpleXML and Retrofit). They looks like:

```
@Root(strict = false)
public class RssFeedChannel {

    @Element(name = "title", required = false)
    String title;

    @Element(name = "language", required = false)
    String language;
...
```

Is it normal practice to reuse these classes also as entities in Greendao for storage parsed data in DB? Or it should be better to create separate classes for storing data? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have a same question as you something like month ago. I'm using greenDAO for caching rss requests. I just save these objects in greenDAO, because annotation only works with a xml converter (when u're serializing object).

Comment: Seems that it is possible to make same class for parsing XML and save them in GreenDAO. Still no issues were found witch such way.

Comment: @Yurik How did you reuse it for GreenDAO? Please put the snippet code.

Comment: @Mr.Hyde, I created some classes that used in SimpleXML and GreenDAO at once. You can see the example of such class here: [link](https://pastebin.com/9CriSii5)